# if statement inside jQuery Validation plugin remote rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have two forms: one for adding a new user and the other for user data modification.

Forms are basically the same, only difference is that when doing modification username field should not be checked if exists in database.

In Js file I do field validations. One of those validations is checking if username already exists in database. In modification this should not be considered.

This is why I thought this, but it's not working:

I differentiate the two forms with div id.

**(view snippet add_user form):**

```
<div id="add_user">
  <form action="{site_url()}admin/updateFrontUser" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
```

**(view snippet edit_user form):**

```
<div id="edit_user">
  <form action="{site_url()}admin/updateFrontUser" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
```

and then:

**(js file snippet)**

```
var algo = $('.add_user', form2);

form2.validate({
            errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
            errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
            focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
            ignore: "",
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true, 
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 15,
                    pattern: "[A-z](([\._\-][A-z0-9])|[A-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*",
                    remote: {

                        data: function(){

                            if (algo) {

                                url: '/admin/checkUsername';
                                type: 'POST';

                            }; 
                        }                               
                    }                    
                },
```

The remote rule it's supposed to check if username exists. That function is already built in my admin.php. It worked previously, before I made the modifications I mentioned.

So to resume, How do I do just to use remote rule only for a new user (I mean, when using add form) ?

Comment: Do you mean like adding 'remote' (without the single quotes) to the class attribute of the element?

Comment: I want to know if it's possible for me to put an if statement inside jquery's rules..

Comment: You are meaning jquery validation's rules. You can create your own rules so yes you can.

Comment: @MikeCheel no.. that's not my question. I know I can do that, in fact I did. I just want to know how to add an if statement inside a rule..

Comment: So you mean existing rules. It depends on the rule (after all they are just 'custom' rules that come out of the box. The 'remote' rule takes an object that uses the jquery ajax options so you can use a function (or if) wherever you could do that in jquery ajax options. So I think it is a case by case basis that depends on the rule.

Comment: If you're using a plugin, then please be specific about that in your OP.  jQuery itself does not have any `validation` or `remote` methods and there are many different jQuery form validation plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below rule

```
$().ready(function() {

                $("#id_frm").validate({
                    rules: {

                        "id_question": {
                           required: true
                        },
                        "id_number": {


                            required: function(){ return $('input:radio[name=id_question]:checked').val() == 'Yes' },
                            minlength: 10,
                            minlength: 10
                        },
                        "contact_method": {
                             required: function(){ return $('input:radio[name=id_question]:checked').val() == 'No' }
                        }


                    },
                    messages: {
                        "id_question": {
                            required: "Please choose if you have an ID or not."
                        },
                        "id_number": {
                            required: "Please Enter ID."
                        },
                        "contact_method": {
                            required: "Please choose a contact method."
                        }               

                    },

            });


        });
```